# How can I debug keyboard interrupts in GDB?

Tags: c, gdb, interrupt, qemu, osdev

Is it possible to trigger and debug IRQ 1 in GDB?

Someone told me i can just

```
hbreak isr_kbd_stub
continue
```

but that only sets a breakpoint, it doesnt trigger IRQ 1,
If I try to press a key in GDB nothing happens

Here's how I run qemu with GDB:

```
 qemu-system-x86_64 -s -S -M q35 -m 2G -cdrom barebones.iso -boot d
```

And here is what i run in GDB:

```
target remote | qemu-system-x86_64 -cdrom barebones.iso -S -gdb stdio -display none \
-serial file:debug.log -smp 2 -machine q35 -m 2G
```

and my keyboard interrupts work, if I run qemu normally I can press a key and IRQ 1 will run, so the problem is not that

Comment: I added tags "qemu" and "osdev" because I think they are quite relevant, however I have to remove "debugging" and "keyboard" because there is a maximum number of 5 tags per question. If you think this is worse, you can change it back.

Comment: Can you not trigger the IRQ by pressing a key?

Comment: @user253751 if  I run qemu normally without gdb, i can press keys and text will print on the screen. If I run it with gdb and `hbreak isr_kbd; continue` i can press keys and text will print on the screen, BUT nothing happens in GDB, it just keeps continuing

Comment: try `break` instead of `hbreak`, does it work?

Comment: @user253751 nope, doesnt work

Comment: Well... how did you come to the conclusion that `isr_kbd_stub` is the function that you should put a breakpoint on? Do you know for sure that this function is being executed? Show a minimal reproducible example of the source code of your OS.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli here is a 30 second video clip of what happens: https://youtu.be/f-xZC5_i0a8

Comment: Stupid question: Are you sure the function isr_kbd_stub gets called?

Comment: We cannot help you without a [mre].